# How can I inject a node object into a service class in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j

I am relatively new to development and to spring framework.

What I want to do is to create a small project where I have a company that has lines, which has projects, which has employees. Also, I am using a Neo4J docker image to save all these objects.

[image]

This is my project structure.

These are my nodes, Employee, Line, Project, respectively.

```
package com.thebman.neo4jstudy.node;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.GeneratedValue;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Id;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Relationship;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

```
package com.thebman.neo4jstudy.node;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.GeneratedValue;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Id;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Relationship;

import java.util.Set;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity
public class Line {

    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Relationship(type = "belongs_to", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<Project> projectSet;
}
```

```
package com.thebman.neo4jstudy.node;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.GeneratedValue;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Id;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.schema.Relationship;

import java.util.Set;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long entityId;
    private String name;
    private String location;

    @Relationship(type = "works_for", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<Employee> employee;

}
```

This is my controller class:

```
package com.thebman.neo4jstudy.controller;

import com.thebman.neo4jstudy.node.Line;
import com.thebman.neo4jstudy.node.Project;
import com.thebman.neo4jstudy.node.Employee;
import com.thebman.neo4jstudy.service.LineService;
import com.thebman.neo4jstudy.service.ProjectService;
import com.thebman.neo4jstudy.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/company")
public class CompanyController {
    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    private LineService lineService;


    @PostMapping("/line/projects")
    ResponseEntity saveProject(@RequestBody Project project) {
        return new ResponseEntity(projectService.saveProject(project), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/line/projects")
    ResponseEntity getProjects() {
        return new ResponseEntity(projectService.getProjects(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/line/projects/{project_name}")
    ResponseEntity deleteProject(@PathVariable String project_name) {
        projectService.deleteProject(project_name);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/line/projects/employee")
    ResponseEntity saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {

        return new ResponseEntity(personService.savePerson(employee), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("/line")
    ResponseEntity saveLine(@RequestBody Line line) {
        return new ResponseEntity( lineService.saveLine(line), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to add employee to {project} with POST request where the endpoint is "/line/projects/{project_name}/employee". However, I really don't know how to do this. One idea of mine is to call a ProjectService instance and add the employee to that project with add method of a Set, but I cannot use

```
@Autowired
    private Project project;
```

inside ProjectService class. When I do that I get error.

How can I achieve what I want to do?

Any help is appreciated.

best,

Comment: Your service is noted with @Service? Can you sharing error log,  your service and repository class?

Comment: I think the problem stems from me not knowing how to map Employee class to project class. I made some changes and edited my post if you wanna take a look. And yes I annotated @Service to my service classes